# how to preserve current state in image gallery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, image-gallery

I have a website(dwarfdog.com/cds_studio) which uses an image thumb gallery and has a next/prev arrow to view move images from that gallery. I can also view a detail page of an image by clicking on to it.

The requirement is when i am navigating to a second/third page in the gallery and click the detail page to view and when i am clicking "back" button on the detail page it takes me to the first page of the gallery rather the one i was in.

This website is developed in PHP(wordpress) for backend coding and jquery for the image gallery section.

Can anyone suggest me how do i preserve the current state of the gallery when i am coming from detail page to gallery page by clicking "back" button?